# How do you de-elevate privileges for a child process

Tags: c#, process, uac, elevation

I know how to launch a process with Admin privileges from a process using:

```
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
proc.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

where proc is a System.Diagnostics.Process.  But how does one do the opposite?

If the process you're in is already elevated, how do you launch the new process without admin privileges? More accurately, we need to launch the new process with the same permission level as Windows Explorer, so no change if UAC is disabled, but if UAC is enabled, but our process is running elevated, we need to perform a certain operation un-elevated because we're creating a virtual drive and if it's created with elevated permissions and Windows explorer is running unelevated it won't show up.

Feel free to change the title to something better, I couldn't come up with a good description.

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/196949/how-to-run-not-elevated-in-vista-net The answer looks scary though.

Comment: Not only is it scary, its not correct. UAC elevation is one way and there is no documented way to go back (Injecting into explorer.exe or using the Task Scheduler is way hacky and probably not a good idea)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We ended up using the sample from this Code Project article: [High elevation can be bad for your application: How to start a non-elevated process at the end of the installation](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/RunNonElevated.aspx)

It seems to work so far, I gather it injects into RunDll32.exe, my C++/Win32 is fairly weak so I didn't look too much into the actual implementation, just it's use.  Confirmed that it works in Vista and Win7 both x86 and x64 (at least for us, x86 and x64 require different dll's which is checked for at install time and the proper one is used).

Answer (score 23):

The solution for you is to use EXPLORER.exe process.

The idea is to run the process in UN-ELEVATED mode, using windows's file explorer process `explorer.exe` ([info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Explorer_%28Windows%29)).
Lets say the process that we want to launch is on `$TEMP\MyUnElevatedProcess.exe`.

So, for NSIS code, I will just write: (but can be run in ANY language)

```
 Exec '"$WINDIR\explorer.exe" "$TEMP\MyUnElevatedProcess.exe"'
```

Example code (**using NSIS installer**)

```
Exec '"$WINDIR\explorer.exe" "$TEMP\MyUnElevatedProcess.exe"'
```

***code taken from http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2013/01/nsis-lunch-program-as-user-from-uac.html

Comment: This is one of the best answers I've seen to start an unelevated process... sadly, I can't use it beacuse I can't capture the stdout or stderr of MyUnElevatedProcess.exe.

Comment: I am trying to use this solution, but the application runs under the Windir folder instead of Temp folder..any solution for this? (i.e. files are relative to windir folder)

Comment: To use this for the check box on the finish page in a Modern UI installer, use two lines. First line: `!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN "$WINDIR\explorer.exe"` and second line: `!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_PARAMETERS "$TEMP\MyUnElevatedProcess.exe"`.

Comment: On the linked page, [a comment from a Microsoft employee(?) is](http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2013/01/nsis-lunch-program-as-user-from-uac.html?showComment=1388694317801#c939517856791332836): "Unfortunately, the Windows Shell team has replied that the current behavior of "Explorer.exe AppName.exe" is a bug and may not work in future updates/versions of Windows. Applications should not rely upon it."

Comment: One last addition: If your parameters contains blanks, you can embed them inside _escaped_ quotes

To embedd your parameters inside quotes (if they contain blanks) `$\"` like: `!define MUI_FINISHPAGE_RUN_PARAMETERS '$\"$TEMP\MyUnElevatedProcess.exe$\"'`.

Comment: Great, very easy solution. But it only works if you don't have to pass arguments because explorer will take the entire argument and checks if it finds an exe there. I solved that by placing a small file with the arguments into the %appData% directory.

Comment: Note that the Shell **typically** uses `explorer.exe`, but this *can* be changed in the Registry, so best not to hard-code the Shell app you use to launch your app.

Answer (score 8):

Raymond Chen addressed this in his blog:

[How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process and vice versa?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=2643)

Searching in [GitHub](https://github.com) for a C# version of this code, I found the following implementation in Microsoft's **Node.js tools for Visual Studio** repository: [SystemUtilities.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/nodejstools/blob/master/Nodejs/Product/Nodejs/SharedProject/SystemUtilities.cs) (the `ExecuteProcessUnElevated` function).

Just in case the file disappears, here's the file's contents:

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft.  All Rights Reserved.  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0.  See License.txt in the project root for license information.

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Microsoft.NodejsTools.SharedProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Utility for accessing window IShell* interfaces in order to use them to launch a process unelevated
    /// </summary>
    internal class SystemUtility
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// We are elevated and should launch the process unelevated. We can't create the
        /// process directly without it becoming elevated. So to workaround this, we have
        /// explorer do the process creation (explorer is typically running unelevated).
        /// </summary>
        internal static void ExecuteProcessUnElevated(string process, string args, string currentDirectory = "")
        {
            var shellWindows = (IShellWindows)new CShellWindows();

            // Get the desktop window
            object loc = CSIDL_Desktop;
            object unused = new object();
            int hwnd;
            var serviceProvider = (IServiceProvider)shellWindows.FindWindowSW(ref loc, ref unused, SWC_DESKTOP, out hwnd, SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH);

            // Get the shell browser
            var serviceGuid = SID_STopLevelBrowser;
            var interfaceGuid = typeof(IShellBrowser).GUID;
            var shellBrowser = (IShellBrowser)serviceProvider.QueryService(ref serviceGuid, ref interfaceGuid);

            // Get the shell dispatch
            var dispatch = typeof(IDispatch).GUID;
            var folderView = (IShellFolderViewDual)shellBrowser.QueryActiveShellView().GetItemObject(SVGIO_BACKGROUND, ref dispatch);
            var shellDispatch = (IShellDispatch2)folderView.Application;

            // Use the dispatch (which is unelevated) to launch the process for us
            shellDispatch.ShellExecute(process, args, currentDirectory, string.Empty, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Interop definitions
        /// </summary>
        private const int CSIDL_Desktop = 0;
        private const int SWC_DESKTOP = 8;
        private const int SWFO_NEEDDISPATCH = 1;
        private const int SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1;
        private const int SVGIO_BACKGROUND = 0;
        private readonly static Guid SID_STopLevelBrowser = new Guid("4C96BE40-915C-11CF-99D3-00AA004AE837");

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("9BA05972-F6A8-11CF-A442-00A0C90A8F39")]
        [ClassInterfaceAttribute(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
        private class CShellWindows
        {
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("85CB6900-4D95-11CF-960C-0080C7F4EE85")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        private interface IShellWindows
        {
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)]
            object FindWindowSW([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref object pvarloc, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] ref object pvarlocRoot, int swClass, out int pHWND, int swfwOptions);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("6d5140c1-7436-11ce-8034-00aa006009fa")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IServiceProvider
        {
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
            object QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("000214E2-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IShellBrowser
        {
            void VTableGap01(); // GetWindow
            void VTableGap02(); // ContextSensitiveHelp
            void VTableGap03(); // InsertMenusSB
            void VTableGap04(); // SetMenuSB
            void VTableGap05(); // RemoveMenusSB
            void VTableGap06(); // SetStatusTextSB
            void VTableGap07(); // EnableModelessSB
            void VTableGap08(); // TranslateAcceleratorSB
            void VTableGap09(); // BrowseObject
            void VTableGap10(); // GetViewStateStream
            void VTableGap11(); // GetControlWindow
            void VTableGap12(); // SendControlMsg
            IShellView QueryActiveShellView();
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("000214E3-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
        private interface IShellView
        {
            void VTableGap01(); // GetWindow
            void VTableGap02(); // ContextSensitiveHelp
            void VTableGap03(); // TranslateAcceleratorA
            void VTableGap04(); // EnableModeless
            void VTableGap05(); // UIActivate
            void VTableGap06(); // Refresh
            void VTableGap07(); // CreateViewWindow
            void VTableGap08(); // DestroyViewWindow
            void VTableGap09(); // GetCurrentInfo
            void VTableGap10(); // AddPropertySheetPages
            void VTableGap11(); // SaveViewState
            void VTableGap12(); // SelectItem

            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)]
            object GetItemObject(UInt32 aspectOfView, ref Guid riid);
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("00020400-0000-0000-C000-000000000046")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        private interface IDispatch
        {
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("E7A1AF80-4D96-11CF-960C-0080C7F4EE85")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        private interface IShellFolderViewDual
        {
            object Application { [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IDispatch)] get; }
        }

        [ComImport]
        [Guid("A4C6892C-3BA9-11D2-9DEA-00C04FB16162")]
        [InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
        public interface IShellDispatch2
        {
            void ShellExecute([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)] string File, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vArgs, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vDir, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vOperation, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)] object vShow);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Raymond also posted a followup article: [How can I launch an unelevated process from my elevated process, redux](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190425-00/?p=102443) utilizing `CreateProcess` instead of `ShellExecute`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start an unelevated process from an elevated one you could copy the access token of the shell process and use it to start a new process.

```
public static class UnelevatedProcessStarter
{
    public static void Start(string cmdArgs)
    {
        // 1. Get the shell
        var shell = NativeMethods.GetShellWindow();
        if (shell == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not find shell window");
        }

        // 2. Copy the access token of the process
        NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(shell, out uint shellProcessId);
        var hShellProcess = NativeMethods.OpenProcess(0x00000400 /* QueryInformation */, false, (int)shellProcessId);
        if (!NativeMethods.OpenProcessToken(hShellProcess, 2 /* TOKEN_DUPLICATE */, out IntPtr hShellToken))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        // 3. Duplicate the acess token
        uint tokenAccess = 8 /*TOKEN_QUERY*/ | 1 /*TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY*/ | 2 /*TOKEN_DUPLICATE*/ | 0x80 /*TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT*/ | 0x100 /*TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID*/;
        var securityAttributes = new SecurityAttributes();

        NativeMethods.DuplicateTokenEx(
            hShellToken,
            tokenAccess,
            ref securityAttributes,
            2 /* SecurityImpersonation */,
            1 /* TokenPrimary */,
            out IntPtr hToken);

        // 4. Create a new process with the copied token
        var si = new Startupinfo();
        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);

        if (!NativeMethods.CreateProcessWithTokenW(
            hToken,
            0x00000002 /* LogonNetcredentialsOnly */,
            null,
            cmdArgs,
            0x00000010 /* CreateNewConsole */,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            null,
            ref si,
            out ProcessInformation _))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }
    }

    public class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int processAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int processId);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr processHandle, UInt32 desiredAccess, out IntPtr tokenHandle);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr hExistingToken, uint dwDesiredAccess,
            ref SecurityAttributes lpTokenAttributes,
            int impersonationLevel,
            int tokenType,
            out IntPtr phNewToken);
        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool CreateProcessWithTokenW(
            IntPtr hToken, int dwLogonFlags,
            string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine,
            int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory, [In] ref Startupinfo lpStartupInfo, out ProcessInformation lpProcessInformation);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ProcessInformation
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SecurityAttributes
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct Startupinfo
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @NtFreX I created another solution, that

1. <s>takes the token from the current identity (seems to work and needs less code),</s> - sorry, that doesn't always work
2. handles running from an already unelevated process (because in this case `CreateProcessWithTokenW` fails with error code 1314 - "A required privilege is not held by the client") and
3. returns the process id so that the calling code can await it etc.

```cs
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;

public static class UnelevatedProcessStarter
{
    public static int Start(string cmdArgs)
    {
        // 1. Get the shell
        var shell = NativeMethods.GetShellWindow();
        if (shell == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            throw new Exception("Could not find shell window");
        }

        // 2. Copy the access token of the process
        uint shellProcessId;
        NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(shell, out shellProcessId);
        var hShellProcess = NativeMethods.OpenProcess(0x00000400 /* QueryInformation */, false, (int)shellProcessId);
        IntPtr hShellToken;
        if (!NativeMethods.OpenProcessToken(hShellProcess, 2 /* TOKEN_DUPLICATE */, out hShellToken))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        // 3. Duplicate the access token
        uint tokenAccess = 8 /*TOKEN_QUERY*/ | 1 /*TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY*/ | 2 /*TOKEN_DUPLICATE*/ | 0x80 /*TOKEN_ADJUST_DEFAULT*/ | 0x100 /*TOKEN_ADJUST_SESSIONID*/;
        var securityAttributes = new SecurityAttributes();
        IntPtr hToken;
        if (!NativeMethods.DuplicateTokenEx(
            hShellToken,
            tokenAccess,
            ref securityAttributes,
            2 /* SecurityImpersonation */,
            1 /* TokenPrimary */,
            out hToken))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        // 4. Create a new process with the copied token
        var si = new Startupinfo();
        si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si);
        ProcessInformation processInfo;
        if (!NativeMethods.CreateProcessWithTokenW(
            hToken,
            0x00000002 /* LogonNetcredentialsOnly */,
            null,
            cmdArgs,
            0x00000010 /* CreateNewConsole */,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            null,
            ref si,
            out processInfo))
        {
            // Can't do that when not elevated (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createprocesswithtokenw)
            // -> start the process as usual
            if (Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() == 1314)
            {
                SecurityAttributes processSecurityAttributes = new SecurityAttributes();
                SecurityAttributes threadSecurityAttributes = new SecurityAttributes();
                if (!NativeMethods.CreateProcessAsUser(
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    null,
                    cmdArgs,
                    ref processSecurityAttributes,
                    ref threadSecurityAttributes,
                    true,
                    0x00000010 /* CreateNewConsole */,
                    IntPtr.Zero,
                    null,
                    ref si,
                    out processInfo))
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Win32Exception();
            }
        }

        return processInfo.dwProcessId;
    }

    public class NativeMethods
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetShellWindow();
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(int processAccess, bool bInheritHandle, int processId);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr processHandle, UInt32 desiredAccess, out IntPtr tokenHandle);
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr hExistingToken, uint dwDesiredAccess,
            ref SecurityAttributes lpTokenAttributes,
            int impersonationLevel,
            int tokenType,
            out IntPtr phNewToken);
        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool CreateProcessWithTokenW(
            IntPtr hToken, int dwLogonFlags,
            string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine,
            int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            [In] ref Startupinfo lpStartupInfo,
            out ProcessInformation lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true, CharSet=CharSet.Unicode)]
        public static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
            IntPtr hToken,
            string lpApplicationName,
            string lpCommandLine,
            ref SecurityAttributes lpProcessAttributes,
            ref SecurityAttributes lpThreadAttributes,
            bool bInheritHandles,
            uint dwCreationFlags,
            IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            string lpCurrentDirectory,
            ref Startupinfo lpStartupInfo,
            out ProcessInformation lpProcessInformation);
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ProcessInformation
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public int dwProcessId;
        public int dwThreadId;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct SecurityAttributes
    {
        public int nLength;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public int bInheritHandle;
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public struct Startupinfo
    {
        public Int32 cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public Int32 dwX;
        public Int32 dwY;
        public Int32 dwXSize;
        public Int32 dwYSize;
        public Int32 dwXCountChars;
        public Int32 dwYCountChars;
        public Int32 dwFillAttribute;
        public Int32 dwFlags;
        public Int16 wShowWindow;
        public Int16 cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use [ProcessStartInfo.UserName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.username.aspx) and [ProcessStartInfo.Password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.password.aspx) to specify the account you want your process to run under.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\system32\whoami.exe");
        var password = new SecureString();
        password.AppendChar('s');
        password.AppendChar('e');
        password.AppendChar('c');
        password.AppendChar('r');
        password.AppendChar('e');
        password.AppendChar('t');
        psi.Password = password;
        psi.UserName = "username";
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you do this if the the username/password is unknown?  Needs to work for any unknown machine

Comment: @Davy8 `Everyone` user seems to be available on all Windows machine. I've tried it but not sure why it still complains about username/password incorrect. Maybe even `Everyone` user has some hidden password? weird.