# How do I temporarily lower elevation

Tags: .net, elevated-privileges

The scenario is that I am running a service as admin.

We have a callout that runs custom code ( think scripting ).  It uses codedom compiling to create an assembly and create a type and invoke a method (based on code).

I want to temporarily drop admin privileges for the duration of the callout and then restore them afterwards.

Comment: So, what's stopping you?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this.  I am imagining creating a class that implements IDisposable and drops elevation in the constructor and restores it in the destructor but I don't know what the calls are to drop elevation and restore it.  I guess I might need to know the current "state" of elevation to be able to restore it later.

Comment: Could you invoke the callout from a separate process (which is started from the service)? If it is possible, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1173630.

Comment: I do run in a separate app domain BUT that app domain does the compilation and the execution.  I'm going to guess that the compilation requires rights that the execution does not.  For example: I compile my dlls to disk.  So I want to lower elevation around the duration of the call where I am actually invoking code.

Comment: If you can compile EXE instead of DLL, then you perhaps can launch it and de-elevate (see previous link).

Comment: What normally happens, from a Windows perspective, is you have an binary that has lower elevation and that calls another binary that needs temporarily-higher elevation.  in .NET, you can create a "sandbox" to run code in a lower elevation, but that has to run in a different AppDomain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up running the code in a sandboxed application domain as described in the link:

How to: Run Partially Trusted Code in a Sandbox

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can "drop" privileges in the way you describe; your service is running as a user, and that user is allowed a certain amount of access. You can ask Windows to temporarily grant you more permissions (which is what UAC is all about) but you can't ask it to give you less!

I would create a second user in the system for the purposes of running the scripts (with an appropriately lower level of access) and impersonate that user for the duration of the custom code.

**[edit]**
Turns out I don't know what I'm talking about. According to this link, UAC is implemented in the reverse manner, by creating a restricted set of permissions and running the code in that context.

[http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2006/09/29/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-*1320*-Part-4-*1320*-User-Account-Control.aspx](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2006/09/29/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-4-_1320_-User-Account-Control.aspx)