# Advanced Installer how to run exe not as admin

Tags: windows-installer, advanced-installer

So I have an installer, that needs to run as admin, but when installation completes, if user chooses to run app from Finish dialog, the app also runs as admin, but I want to run not as admin. Could not find any answers related to this topic.

This is the screenshot, from finish dialog:

[image]

What I need to do to change permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this answer on the Advanced Installer forums](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=9724), seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Nope, this answer does not help... There is no Media/Bootstrapper section in the Advanced Installer

Comment: That's from an older version, in the current version Media page was renamed to "Builds". Also you can use the left menu search (upper left corner) to search for the options.

Comment: Yeah I found Boostrapper section in Builds, but there is no section about invokes

Comment: Sorry, it seems you're hitting all kinds of GUI changes. That option is now in Install Parameters page. There you can find a hyperlink "Execution level...".

Comment: This option is for installer itself. I need installer to run as administrator, but installed exe file not as administrator

Comment: The installer will still elevate, but not from the beginning, just as the user said in our forums post. Why do you need you installer to run as admin from the first moment?

Comment: There might be a lot of reasons... For example installer has to install a driver or install and run service

Comment: For those the installer does not have to elevate from the beginning. The installation will elevate automatically, when the user presses the "Install" button. Just as the other user mentioned on our forums. Give it a try and disable the elevation, if it does not work you can enable it back.

Comment: OP wants elevation for the installer, but then needs the executable to launch in the installing user's security context, rather than the elevated context.  You'll likely need to include an executable in your installer which can launch the executable you want to launch at the end in the installing user's context.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1173630/how-do-you-de-elevate-privileges-for-a-child-process