# Call webpage from program

Tags: c#

I would like my c# program to call a webpage when it opens.  The code in the webpage will increment a counter... thus I just need the program to call the page.  Don't think that I need to post or get or anything else.

Thoughts?

Comment: Your requirements aren't quite clear. Are you asking how to do a GET from C#? How is this counter implemented?

Comment: You will need to use POST if you're changing the state of the web server. Look into http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.aspx

Comment: "webpage will increment a counter" sounds bad

Comment: Call it how? I mean, in a browser or in a browser-component in the program?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a web page from my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502199/how-to-open-a-web-page-from-my-application)

Comment: Is this to measure user usage? What if their Internet is down?

Answer (score 1):

for more information check out  [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx)

```
// Create a request for the URL. 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create (
"http://www.contoso.com/default.html");
// If required by the server, set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
// Display the status.
Console.WriteLine (((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();
// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);
// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();
// Display the content.
Console.WriteLine (responseFromServer);
// Clean up the streams and the response.
reader.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

if you can't extract the code you need from the above.. here it is

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.mysite.com/counter.php?YourId");
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
response.Close ();
```

Comment: Essentially the webpage is www.mywebsite.com/counter.php?theID
I don't care about how reliable the process is.
counter.php will take theID and do stuff with it... I don't need to pass along credentials or anything.

Answer (score 0):

I know its late but for future people who might fall onto this.

```
System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com"));
```

Comment: I am curious why this was down voted? I will gladly delete it if there is a valid reason.