# Value of combobox in vb?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

so I'm doing a project where I need to set each item in a bombobox. example:
Combobox in "Google" and "Facebook" just below the combobox has a webbrowser and when I press a button, the browser navigates to the desired link, I have done this part, appears the problem is that I do not know how to set the link for each item , to set www.google.com for Google option and even in facebook .. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The combobox has 2 properties that you can use for this purpose. The DisplayMember is what you see in the GUI and the ValueMember is what you can use to navigate to based on the user selection. Example:

```
        Dim myDt As New DataTable() 'define a datatable to hold the combo box data   
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.Add("Site")
        dt.Columns.Add("URL")
        '*** Load the combobox with data
        dt.Rows.Add("Google", "www.google.com")
        dt.Rows.Add("Facebook", "www.facebook.com")
        '***add other rows you might have here

        '*** now bind the datatable to the combobox
        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "Site"  'for example Google
        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "URL"     'for example www.Google.com
```

In your chosen event, afte the user selects an entry from the combobox, you could issue:

```
'***Launch the site that corresponds to the selected item in the combobox 
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ComboBox1.SelectedValue)
```

You could use other means to initiate the navigation to selected site, for example: [Open Web Page from App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502199/how-to-open-a-web-page-from-my-application).