# How to open a website from within a C# Winforms application

Tags: c#, winforms, system.diagnostics

Given a Winforms application with a button - how can it open a specific URL/website from within this application by clicking the button?

Comment: "my button" in what? what have you tried/researched?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a web page from my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/502199/how-to-open-a-web-page-from-my-application)

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.page.com");
```

Original answer: [How to open a web page from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502199/how-to-open-a-web-page-from-my-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can to that by command line

```
"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" www.google.com
```

Read about [Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) class

```
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "command there";
        myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: This assumes you want to force IE on the user. Using `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` will use the user's default web browser.