# Is there a way to open a website in the default browser in c#?

Tags: c#, console-application

I am a c# noob and I am making a console app to sporadically make you lose [the game](https://losethegame.com) by open the website and writing "the game!"

I am trying to make it open a link to the game's website, but it does not work.
What I am using, but doesn't work is what MS docs says which is
`System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://website.com");`
I use windows 11, MS edge for default browser.

Comment: what doesn't work?

Comment: This is how you open websites from C#. If it doesn't work, please specify what is your OS and your default browser?

Comment: You will not see the website open from the console app - your browser will just have a tab with that url open.

Answer (score 1):

[How to open a web page from my application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502199/how-to-open-a-web-page-from-my-application)

the default for the `useShellExecute` is now false, so you have to explicitly set it as true.

Comment: If another post has the answer, we don't copy/paste the content, we mark the question as a duplicate. Please don't post answers like this. Thanks